# Can someone help with advice in regards to MetaMask?

Tags: metamask, meta-transactions

MetaMask showing a token price 10-100x the current value of a token.
The token is a native token on a mainnet that currently has low liquidity as it’s in the auditing stage,
Now the community/future investors are seeing the fictitious price and asking too many questions, we contacted MetaMask and they was stumped at why a token not currently listed on coingecko was showing a current value as they normally receive information from the API from them, they seem to think it’s pulling the price from the networks RPC, it’s confusing a lot of us, can anyone suggest anything that can be changed or have any information regarding this issue. They advised getting help from here, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thankyou